# Configuring XP-Pen graphics tablet on linux (specifically wayland)

Tags: wayland, tablet

I've acquired myself XP-Pen Deco mini 7 graphics tablet. Pointer and pressure work out of the box, but I want to rotate it to left-hand mode and change actions on pad and stylus buttons.

I'm using [Sway](https://swaywm.org/) wayland compositor on archlinux.

Answer (score 1):

### Preface

There is official linux "driver" [on XP-Pen website](https://www.xp-pen.com/download-525.html) (also [aur package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xp-pen-tablet)). From what I was able to discern it is a user-space app (linked with X11-only Qt5), which is supposed to autostart with DE and somehow interact with tablet over USB. It comes with udev rule to make XP-Pen USB device writeable for normal user.

`strace` showed that it tried every USB device (`/dev/bus/usb/*/*`) but in the end wasn't able to find my tablet. Maybe you'll have better luck with it

### Tablet events handling overview

```
                                         +————————————————+
                                         |                |
                                         |  Wayland       |
                                         |  compositor    |
                                         |                |
+——————————+  event  +—————————+  event  +——————————————+ |  event  +———————+
|  Tablet  |————————>|  Linux  |————————>|   libinput   | |————————>|  app  |
+——————————+         +—————————+         |              | |         +———————+
                                         | +——————————+ | |
                                         | | libwacom | | |
                                         +—+——————————+—+—+
```

Wayland compositor (Sway, Mutter, KWin through Qt) uses [libinput](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/what-is-libinput.html) to handle input devices and their event. It in turn uses [libwacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom) for hardware information about tablet (number of buttons, their codes, if stylus has "rubber" tip, etc.)

*libinput* can be used with X11 through [xf86-input-libinput](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/what-is-libinput.html#libinput-and-x-org) so following steps aren't limited to Wayland.

### Left-hand mode

If *libwacom* reports that tablet is "reversible", *libinput* can be configured to translate pointer events from it to left-hand mode.

Basically *libwacom* is a database of known graphics tablets, each described in `.tablet` file (see [whole list](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/tree/c16eb9536094f8cdbc4755b0ee10e4cbe134fdf3/data) in repo).

You can check if *libwacom* knows your tablet:

```
$ libwacom-list-local-devices
/dev/input/event19 is a tablet but not supported by libwacom
Failed to find any devices known to libwacom.
```

If not, you'll have to create `.tablet` yourself. For XP-Pen Deco mini 7 I've made following file at `/usr/share/libwacom/xp-pen-deco-mini-7.tablet`:

```
# XP-Pen
# Deco mini7
#

[Device]
Name=XP-Pen Deco mini7
ModelName=
DeviceMatch=usb:28bd:0928
Class=Bamboo
Width=7
Height=4.37
Styli=0xffffd;

[Features]
Stylus=true
Reversible=true
Touch=false
Buttons=0
```

Most important are two options:

- `DeviceMatch` specifies how to identify tablet and has format `BUS:VENDOR_ID:MODEL_ID`. You can find this values with `udevadm`:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/input/event19
...
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=28bd
...
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0928
...
E: ID_BUS=usb
```

- `Reversible` indicates that tablet can be used in left-hand mode.

(more details and description for other options can be found in [example in repo](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/blob/c16eb9536094f8cdbc4755b0ee10e4cbe134fdf3/data/wacom.example))

Verify that libwacom now recognizes the tablet:

```
$ libwacom-list-local-devices
devices:
- name: 'XP-Pen Deco mini7'
  bus: 'usb'
  vid: '0x28bd'
  pid: '0x0928'
  nodes:
  - /dev/input/event19
```

Now you can configure *libinput* through your compositor. For Sway add to your config

```
input type:tablet_tool left_handed enabled
```

For [Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/wacom-left-handed.html.en) and [KDE](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Input_Devices/en#Tablet) you can use system settings GUI.

**NOTE** you may need to replug tablet to apply configuration.

### Pad and stylus buttons mapping

XP-Pen sends pad button events as separate keyboard device. You can see them with `evtest` (here buttons are already mapped):

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event18
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x28bd product 0x928 version 0x100
Input device name: "UGTABLET 6 inch PenTablet Keyboard"
Supported events:
...
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1648039909.676558, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1648039909.676558, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1648039909.676558, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70056
Event: time 1648039909.676558, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 44 (KEY_Z), value 1
Event: time 1648039909.676558, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo evtest /dev/input/event18
$ fg
sudo evtest /dev/input/event18
Event: time 1648039909.764562, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1648039909.764562, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1648039909.764562, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70056
Event: time 1648039909.764562, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 44 (KEY_Z), value 0
Event: time 1648039909.764562, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648039944.475630, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1648039944.475630, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1648039944.475630, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70057
Event: time 1648039944.475630, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 183 (KEY_F13), value 1
Event: time 1648039944.475630, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648039944.551696, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1648039944.551696, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1648039944.551696, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70057
Event: time 1648039944.551696, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 183 (KEY_F13), value 0
Event: time 1648039944.551696, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

(this is result of pressing first two buttons. Since one of them was mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `bash` suspended `evtest`)

They can be mapped with [hwdb(7)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/systemd/hwdb.7.en). Create file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/62-xp-pen-deco-mini-7.hwdb` with contents:

```
evdev:input:b0003v28BDp0928*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70005=kp0
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70008=kp1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e2=kp2
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7002c=f16
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70016=f15
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7001d=f14
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70057=f13
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70056=z
```

First line matches device similar to `.tablet` file and has format `b{BUS_ID}v{VENDOR_ID}p{MODEL_ID}`. For USB `{BUS_ID}` is `0003`.

Then you write scancode to key mappings in format `KEYBOARD_KEY_{scancode}={key}`. Scancodes are obtained from `evtest` output (`MSC_SCAN` lines), key names can be found in `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h` and must be in lowercase. In example above I map all but last buttons to generic keys, so then I can bind specific actions to them on per application basis.

For XP-Pen Deco mini 7 default mapping is:

- 70005 — b
- 70008 — e
- 700e2 — leftalt
- 7002c — space
- 700e2, 70016 — leftctrl, s
- 700e2, 7001d — leftctrl, z
- 700e2, 70057 — leftctrl, kpplus
- 700e2, 70056 — leftctrl, kpminus

but these are different for every tablet model.

**NOTE** Since I don't map scancode `700e2`, last four keys will be emitted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Stylus buttons events are generated on tablet input itself:

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event19
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x28bd product 0x928 version 0x100
Input device name: "UGTABLET 6 inch PenTablet"
...
Event: time 1648041701.178269, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648041701.686282, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0044
Event: time 1648041701.686282, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 331 (BTN_STYLUS), value 1
Event: time 1648041701.786243, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648041701.790243, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0044
Event: time 1648041701.790243, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 331 (BTN_STYLUS), value 0
Event: time 1648041704.130289, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648041704.134281, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0045
Event: time 1648041704.134281, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 277 (BTN_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1648041704.262281, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1648041704.266286, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0045
Event: time 1648041704.266286, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 277 (BTN_FORWARD), value 0
```

By default lower button (scancode `d0044`) resulted in "Middle mouse button press" event, which was pretty convenient, but upper had no visible effect. There are two possible ways to utilize it:

- map to arbitrary mouse button and bind action to this button in application

```
KEYBOARD_KEY_d0045=btn_forward
```

- map to `BTN_TOOL_RUBBER` to emulate "rubber" pen tip

```
KEYBOARD_KEY_d0045=btn_tool_rubber
```

Add preferred variant to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/62-xp-pen-deco-mini-7.hwdb`, then compile binary hwdb

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

and apply mappings to devices:

```
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

**NOTE** you may need to replug you tablet and/or restart DE applications to use this mappings.

Answer (score 1):

For handling all the options such as drawing area, left-hand mode, aspect ratio, pressure of the pen and other, follow the [self-answer of MadRunner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696515/377345) (Paragraph Left-hand mode).

Once the `.tablet` configuration has been created if you want to contribute to the `libwacom` project (so that those arriving after you will not have to do this procedure) please make a pull request following these instructions: ["Contribute to `libwacom`"](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Tablet-Definition-Files#gathering-sysinfo)

To change the actions of the graphics tablet buttons, there is a simpler method.
You can use [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's also trying to do this, after spending 4 hours trying to make it work, try using

```
evdev:name:(name of device):*
```

instead of

```
evdev:input:b0003v28BDp0928*
```

Thank you so much for the answer btw! Though I still haven't figured out how to make the `btn_middle` work with scroll.